# Alterando a cor de Elementos HTML que ainda não existem

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Eu preciso que o backgroundcolor de elementos div sejam alterados quando passar o mouse por cima, porém esses elementos ainda não existem, serão criados ao pressionar um botão, eu já tentei por algumas horas pensar em alguma solução, mas nada vem na minha cabeça.

Obs. Eu consigo criar os elementos div, só não consigo alterar a cor passando o mouse por cima.

segue o código JS

```html
var boxContainer = document.querySelector('#box');
var btnElement = document.querySelector('button');
var getBox = document.getElementsByClassName('createBox');

btnElement.onclick = function creatingBoxes(){

    var boxCreator = document.createElement('div');

    boxCreator.setAttribute('class', 'createBox');
    boxCreator.style.width = "100px";
    boxCreator.style.height = "100px";
    boxCreator.style.backgroundColor = '#f00';
    boxContainer.insertBefore(boxCreator, btnElement);
}

getBox.onmouseover = function changingColorOfBoxes() {
    
    var newColor = getRandomColor(); // #E943F0
    getBox.style.backgroundColor = newColor;
    
}

function getRandomColor(){
    var letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";  
    var color = "#";  
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {   
         color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];  
    } 
    return color; 
}
```

Comment: Eu fiz esse exemplo: https://repl.it/repls/AnotherVacantPostscript , que usa a [API CSS Paint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Painting_API) para gerar uma função CSS de  preenchimento personalizado(cores aleatórias) que é aplicada via folha de estilo a todos os elementos cujo o atributo `class="createBox"` sejam diâmicos ou não. Não publiquei como resposta pois a pergunta parece ser bem específica sobre javascript, então fica como curiosidade.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você já entendeu que o problema é tentar acessar um elemento quando ele ainda não existe. Então por que não simplesmente deixar para atribuir tratamento do mouseover no momento da criação? Assim:

```js
var boxContainer = document.querySelector('#box');
var btnElement = document.querySelector('button');

btnElement.onclick = function creatingBoxes(){

    var boxCreator = document.createElement('div');

    boxCreator.setAttribute('class', 'createBox');
    boxCreator.style.width = "100px";
    boxCreator.style.height = "100px";
    boxCreator.style.backgroundColor = '#f00';
    boxContainer.appendChild(boxCreator);
    
    boxCreator.onmouseover = function changingColorOfBoxes() {   
        var newColor = getRandomColor(); // #E943F0
        this.style.backgroundColor = newColor;

    }
}


function getRandomColor(){
    var letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";  
    var color = "#";  
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {   
         color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];  
    } 
    return color; 
}
```

```html
<button type="button">
Novo box
</button>

<div id="box">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, perfeito a sua solução, eu dps de algumas horas pensando tinha chego em algo bem próximo do seu código, porém ainda não funfou hehe. 
Cara se tiver como vc me ajudar a entender pq o brownser diz que a váriavel "CHANGE" da função "changingColorOfBoxes" tem o valor como indefinido eu agradeçeria, to quebrando a cabeça com isso.

Ps. a sua solução é melhor doq a minha hehe principalmente pq ta funcionando, mas eu sinto que to prox de conseguir usando a minha lógica, só precisava entender pq a variável change não ta conseguindo buscar as tags pela classe.

```js
var boxContainer = document.querySelector('#box');
var btnElement = document.querySelector('button');
var count=1;

/*
    Esta função cria as caixas usando as tags <p> e define o nome da class de cada tag
    e também define o atributo do mouseover 

*/

btnElement.onclick = function creatingBoxes(){

    var boxCreator = document.createElement('p');

    boxContainer.insertBefore(boxCreator, btnElement);
    boxCreator.setAttribute('class', ''+count+'');
    boxCreator.style.width = "100px";
    boxCreator.style.height = "100px";
    boxCreator.style.backgroundColor = '#f00';
    boxCreator.setAttribute('onmouseover', 'changingColorOfBoxes('+count+')');

    count++;
}


//Esta funçao pega o nome da classe e altera o seu background-color

function changingColorOfBoxes(count) {
    
    var newColor = getRandomColor();
    var change = document.getElementsByClassName(""+count+"");

    change.style.backgroundColor = newColor;
}

//Esta função gera um valor de cor aleatória

function getRandomColor(){
    var letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";  
    var color = "#";  
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {   
         color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];  
    } 
    return color; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="box">
            <button class="btn">Adicionar nova caixa</button>
        </div>
        <script src="changingColor.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```